# how to create dynamic column in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working with a kendo grid and I'm trying to create no. of column based on the no. of members in the database tbl_account . For example :- if a tbl_account has 2 members then the grid should display 2 column.

Is there any way to achieve this ? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my project I created dynamically columns at runtime. I posted the razor code here:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/ie-8-bug-column-resize-handle-not-showing-on-dynamic-grid-columns.aspx#2475693